# "Send" button to change color and message on sent using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms, animation, submit-button

So I am trying to create a form with a submit button that changes its color and message once it has been submitted. Both the code for submission through [AJAX and PHP] and button animation works on their own. However, I can't seem to get them working together. For some reason, it seems that the AJAX is cancelling or stopping the animation from running once the submit button has been clicked. Can someone point me in the right direction? The first part of the code triggers the button animation and the bottom half of the code triggers a post request to a php script to send an email to the person.

```
var submitButton = $('#submitme');              // Variable to cache button element
var alertBox = $('.alert-box');                 // Variable to cache meter element
var closeButton = $('.close');                  // Variable to cache close button element

$(submitButton).click(function() { // Initiates the send interaction.
    if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {
        $(this).fadeOut(500); // Fades out submit button when it's clicked
        setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
             $(alertBox).fadeIn(500); // Fades in success alert
        }, 500);
    }   
}); 

$(closeButton).click(function() { // Initiates the reset function
    $(alertBox).fadeOut(500); // Fades out success message
    setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
        $('input, textarea').not('input[type=submit]').val(''); // Resets the input fields
        $(submitButton).fadeIn(500); // Fades back in the submit button
    }, 500);

    return false; // This stops the success alert from being removed as we just want to hide it
});

//AJAX code
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(submitButton).click(function() {

        var name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var subject    = $('input[name=subject]').val();
        var comment    = $('textarea[name=comment]').val();

        if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {

            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'name':name, 'email':email, 'subject':subject, 'comment':comment};

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('form-processing.php', post_data, function(response){  

                //load json data from server and output message    
                if(response.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{ 
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }

                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: First, you probably want to bind it to FORM SUBMIT, not submitbutton CLICK.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7st7q/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var submitButton = $('#submitme');              // Variable to cache button element
    var alertBox = $('.alert-box');                 // Variable to cache meter element
    var closeButton = $('.close');                  // Variable to cache close button element

    $(submitButton).click(function() { // Initiates the send interaction.
        $("#commentForm").validate();
        if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {
            $(this).fadeOut(500); // Fades out submit button when it's clicked
            setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
                 alertBox.fadeIn(500); // Fades in success alert
            }, 500);
        }   
    }); 

    $(closeButton).click(function() { // Initiates the reset function
        alertBox.fadeOut(500); // Fades out success message
        setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
            $('input, textarea').not('input[type=button]').val(''); // Resets the input fields
            submitButton.fadeIn(500); // Fades back in the submit button
        }, 500);

        return false; // This stops the success alert from being removed as we just want to hide it
    });

    //AJAX code
    $(submitButton).click(function() {   
        var name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var subject    = $('input[name=subject]').val();
        var comment    = $('textarea[name=comment]').val();

        if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {
            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'name':name, 'email':email, 'subject':subject, 'comment':comment};
            //Ajax post data to server

           // $.post('/link.php', post_data, function(response){  
                //load json data from server and output message    
                //if(response.type == 'error')
                //{
                //    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //}//else{ 
                  output = '<div class="success">This is the post respnose.</div>';
                //}

                $("#result").html('ffasdf').slideDown('slow');
           // }, 'json');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's not getting the effect that I want. Eventually I end up just using the ajax function in jquery and everything works for now on desktop, however it seems that on mobile device, the ajax call to the php script to process and send the email seems to be broken.

```
//AJAX code
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(submitButton).click(function() {

        if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {

            //data to be sent to server
            //post_data = {'name':name, 'email':email, 'subject':subject, 'comment':comment};
            post_data = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&comment=' + comment;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "form-processing.php",
                data: post_data,
                success: function() {
                    //display message back to user here
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```